# appbar is not positioning correctly

Tags: android, android-appbarlayout

In my coordinator layout I included another layout which causes AppBarLayout to move to the top and positioned under the status bar,in other words the toolbar height is the half size of it's real height, why is this happening? And also the title of the toolbar is not positioning properly.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/ma_main">



<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/ma_appbar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/ma_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.popup"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<include layout="@layout/main_activity_recycler"/>


<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/ma_fab"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/ma_recycler_layout"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    android:src="@drawable/pencil"
    android:elevation="8dp" />
   </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and included layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
android:id="@+id/ma_recycler_layout">



<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/ma_recyclerView"
    android:visibility="invisible">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

<ProgressBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/ma_progressbar"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    /></LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

make some changes in xml like below ..

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/ma_appbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/ma_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.popup" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

<include layout="@layout/rl" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/ma_fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:elevation="8dp"
    android:src="@drawable/pencil"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/ma_recycler_layout"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end" />
```

```
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

then after recyler view layout like below ..

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
android:id="@+id/ma_recycler_layout">



<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/ma_recyclerView"
    android:visibility="invisible">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

<ProgressBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/ma_progressbar"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    /></RelativeLayout>
```